# ML.Net - load data from csv without specifying index

Tags: .net, machine-learning, ml.net

All documentation examples I've found require to specify column index when loading csv data, even if column title is defined. But there's a common use-case when you have training data with 'Label' column and test data that doesn't have it. So I'd have to either define a separate model with different indexes if I define model class with `[LoadColumn(index)]` attribute or specify different indexes if I use `TextLoader.Column("name", DataKind.BL, index)`.

Is there a way to load data based on column name from csv header instead of column indexes?

Comment: You can do a range of columns. Would that help?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you, I still have to specify indexes instead of names, and they still change if 'Label' column is missing. So, no, that wouldn't help